# Init prop for initialRouteName in Tab Navigator in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator

I have a Tab Navigator in a Component, but to set the first router when showing in a tab by the value of props, I don't know how, Can someone help me with the problem this

My code as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';



const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        A: {

            screen: (props) => (
                <A />
            )
        },
        B: {
            screen: (props) => (
                <B  />
            )
        },
        C: {
            screen: (props) => (
                <C  />
            )
        }
    },
    {
    
        initialRouteName: props.initRouter
    }
);

const TopTab = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default TopTab;
```

Edit: Version react-navigation I use:

```
 "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.5",
```

Comment: Add your `react-navigation` version.

Comment: Yep. I added the version above the post